# How to filter on the Groupby Criterion in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Suppose the following contrived setup:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'fname': ['bob', 'Bob', 'larry', 'LARRY', 'Larry', 'Dick'], 
     'lname': ['harris', 'Larson', 'Douglas', 'REDMOND', 'Beal', 'Dyke']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
g = df.groupby(df.fname.str.lower())

query = ['bob', 'dick', 'chris']
```

In plain english, I want to create a view of the overall Dataframe, for entries whose first name are in the query, ignoring case change.
I (think I) would like to do the equivalent of an efficient and idiomatic `filter()` on `g` to find and combine those groups that correspond to entries in `query`, into a single DataFrame, viz:

```
   fname    lname
0    bob   harris
1    Bob   Larson
5   Dick     Dyke
```

However, `filter()` seems to iterate over the entire set of groups (important when `df` is huge and `query` is small), and anyway I can't seem to access the group-name from within `filter()` anyway.

The best I could come up with:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame()] + map(lambda y: g.get_group(y), 
                                 filter(lambda x: x in g.groups, query)))
```

But I suspect this is not efficient or idiomatic.

UPDATE:

I should have clarified that in the real world problem backing this, there is only one, very large `df`, but there are several independent, small `query` instances.  `isin` would probably work fine for just one query, but I've found considerable speed-up using the `Groupby` once, followed by individual lookups per query into it as written with the map/filter combo above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I am missing something here but simple boolean indexing using isin looks enough.

```
df[df.fname.str.lower().isin(query)]

    fname   lname
0   bob     harris
1   Bob     Larson
5   Dick    Dyke
```

Comment: I might have overthought things, but was assuming that OP had a reason for grouping that data. I only went along the same lines. +1

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, yeah we don't know what does the OP need yet but I felt that groupby was not needed

Answer (score 1):

```
df[(df.fname.str.lower()).str.contains(r'|'.join(query),regex=True)]
Out[20]: 
  fname   lname
0   bob  harris
1   Bob  Larson
5  Dick    Dyke
```